# Facebook Achievement URL

Tags: facebook, achievements

I tried creating an achievement and saw myself having to create a new page with the open graph tags describing the achievements and left the content of the page empty. I was able to register and publish the achievement to a user and finally I was able to click on the achievement. The problem is that when a user sees their friends achievement and clicks on it, they are getting redirected to that empty page that I created that only contains the open graph tags describing the achievement.

My expected outcome was that a user would click on the achievement in the ticker, and be redirected to the game, not the actual achievements url. Is this how achievements work? I promise I've clicked on achievements and being taken to the game who published the achievement.

Comment: Marking a question down without any comments is really unhelpful. Would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this meta tag to your achievement html page, to redirect users to your apps.
The [facebook linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will still be able to register your achievement.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=https://apps.facebook.com/my_apps">
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the empty open graph page redirect to the game via javascript.